# VBA How to copy range data without headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem because I have code that copies entire columns, but I would like to change this code to copy only the values under the headers because in the second file I have pivot tables set. copy vintage file but would like to start with A2: C2

```
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A:D").ClearContents
wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("A:C").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("H").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should work..

```
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A:D").ClearContents
wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Range("A2:C" & rows.count-1).Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Range("H2:H" & rows.count-1).Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Amazing thanks , i habe one more qeustion if i would like remove here " wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A:D").ClearContents : start from A2:D2 without headers how it will be look ?

Comment: Instead of .copy use Clear Contents

wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A2:D" & rows.count-1).ClearContents